How to Ensure Subquery Returns All Associated Records When Using Search Filter in MySQL?
I’m working on a MySQL query to fetch states along with their associated zones using JSON array aggregation based on multiple search criteria. I want to search by either the state attributes or the zone attributes. When I search by state name or code, the query works fine, and I get all associated zones. However, when I search by zone name, it fails to return the expected results, instead of specific zone, it returns all associated zones/records belongs to the state.
Desired Outcome

Search by either state name, state code, or zone name.
When a state matches, return all associated zones, even if they don’t individually match the search term.
When a zone name matches, return that zone along with the associated state.

// Count query
const countQuery = `
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT state.id) AS count
    FROM
        main.states AS state
    INNER JOIN
        organization AS organization
    ON 
        state.org_id = organization.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        main.zones AS zone
    ON 
        state.id = zone.state_id
    WHERE
        state.org_id = :orgId
        AND (
            state.name LIKE :searchBy
            OR state.code LIKE :searchBy
            OR zone.name LIKE :searchBy
        )
`;

// Fetch query
const fetchQuery = `
    SELECT 
        state.id,
        state.code,
        state.org_id,
        state.created_at,
        state.name AS name,
        organization.name AS org_name,
        COALESCE(
            (
                SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                    JSON_OBJECT(
                        'id', zone.id,
                        'name', zone.name,
                        'time_zone', zone.timezone
                    )
                )
                FROM
                    main.zones AS zone
                WHERE
                    zone.state_id = state.id
                ORDER BY
                    zone.name ASC
            ),
            JSON_ARRAY()
        ) AS zones
    FROM
        main.states AS state
    INNER JOIN
        delivery.organization AS organization
    ON 
        state.org_id = organization.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        main.zones AS zone
    ON 
        state.id = zone.state_id
    WHERE
        state.org_id = :orgId
        AND (
            state.name LIKE :searchBy
            OR state.code LIKE :searchBy
            OR zone.name LIKE :searchBy
        )
    GROUP BY 
        state.id, organization.name
    ORDER BY
        state.name ASC
    LIMIT :limit
    OFFSET :offset
`;


You should use separate queries if you have different logic depending on which column matches. You can then combine them with UNION.
